# ssh-add with argument -

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, ssh-keys

I tried to add generated ssh id_rsa to the `gitlab-ci`.

Command I have found is `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | ssh-add -`.
I can not find any information about param `-` that was added to command `ssh-add`.
How can I interprate this?
In a `man` I have found information about running it without any argument and some flags but add single dash is not describe there.
I used ubuntu latest image for this process

Comment: It's a reference to the standard input of the command, so the output of the piped `echo`

Comment: So command `echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > ssh-add` should also works?

Comment: `>` redirects to a file, you'd just be writing the private key in a file named `ssh-add`. If it worked as a pipe, it might still fail since you didn't write `-` this time and `ssh-add` might ignore its standard input (although that would surprise me)

Answer (score 1):

As @Aaron said

```
It's a reference to the standard input of the command, so the output of the piped echo
```